# Code ignitier MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting an error with this function:

**Controller**

```
    $data['carSubwoofers'] = $this->db->get_where("department = 'MOBILE AUDIO' 
                             AND class = 'CAR STEREO' 
                             AND subclass 
                             IN ('SO CAR STEREO','SUBS','SO SUBS')")->result();


$this->load->view('Category/carSubwoofers',$data);
```

**View**

```
foreach($data->result() as $row) { ?>
 <?php echo $row->modelNumber; ?>
     <?php echo $row->name; ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Code igniter shoots out this:

```
A Database Error Occurred
```

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''MOBILE AUDIO' AND class = 'CAR STEREO' AND subclass IN ('SO CAR STEREO' at line 2

SELECT * FROM (`department` = 'MOBILE AUDIO' AND class = 'CAR STEREO' AND subclass IN ('SO CAR STEREO', `'SUBS'`, `'SO` SUBS'))

Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\CodeIgniter_2.0.2\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: I'm not seeing a table name anywhere in that query, nor am I seeing the "WHERE" keyword.  I haven't used Code Igniter, but shouldn't some part of $this->db->get_where(...) specify a table object?  How does that statement know what it's querying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain your conditionals together to make it look cleaner too.

```
$this->db->where('department', 'MOBILE AUDIO')->where('class', 'CAR STEREO')->where_in('subclass', array('SO CAR STEREO','SUBS','SO SUBS'))->get('tableName');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your get_where() is totally off the documentation...

`$query = $this->db->get_where('TABLE', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);`

from the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

so you would want something like `$this->db->get_where("TABLE", array('MOBILE AUDIO' => 'CAR STEREO','class' =>'CAR STEREO'...)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know codeigniter, but it looks like you've forgotten to assign $this->db a table to query.

Comment: checking the docs i ran across http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html  get_where requires a table name and the where statement should be the second param.